# Sigmund vs. Sigismund

Tags: person-names

I am aware that this is not a question strictly related to the German Language, but I think it is still related.

I currently read a book where the name **Sigmund** appears a lot. However, my brain prefers to read (almost always) **Sigismund**.

The question is: are these two names actually related? Are they forms of the same name?

Answer (score 6):

*Sigmund* and *Sigismund* are different forms of the same name.

According to Wikipedia the name derives from Old High German *sigu* (victory) and *munt* (*hand*, *protection*). Tacitus latinised the name as *Segismundis*.

There are many monarchs with this name:

- A 6th century Burgundian king and Catholic saint who is known alternatively as [*Siegmund* or *Sigismund*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigismund_of_Burgundy).
- A Holy Roman Emperor (15th century) named [Sigismund of Luxembourg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigismund,_Holy_Roman_Emperor). The fact that he had also been crowned king of Bohemia, Croatia and Hungary might have contributed to spreading the name.
- Kings of Poland, Sweden and Lithuania, many other princes.

In the article on Polish king [Zygmunt III Waza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigismund_III_Vasa) (as called in Polish) you can see that he signed as *Sigismundus Rex*. Thus, Polish *Zygmunt* and Latin *Sigismundus* are the same.

In German you may encounter various versions. The version *Sigismund* is, as far as I can tell without searching for statistics, no longer common as a first name, but exists as a name for historical persons. *Siegmund* or *Sigmund* are less outdated.